# Understanding join()

Tags: java, join, multithreading, scjp

Suppose a thread `A` is running. I have another thread, `B`, who's not. B has been started, is on runnable state.

What happens if I call: `B.join()`?

Will it suspend the execution of `A` or will it wait for A's `run()` method to complete?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a small code example; I'm not understanding your question as written.  Are you calling B.join() from A?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[join()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) will make the currently executing thread to wait for the the thread it is called on to die.

So - If A is running, and you call B.join(), A will stop executing until B ends/dies.

Comment: the question is unclear and this answer is just as vague. downvoting

Answer (score 8):

Join waits till the thread is dead. If you call it on a dead thread, it should return immediately. Here's a demo:

```
public class Foo extends Thread {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        try {
            // uncomment the following line to start the foo thread.
            // foo.start();
            foo.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finish");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Foo.run()");
    }

}
```

Comment: On the menu https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(). It should have said what you wrote: "If you call it on a dead thread, it should return immediately."

Answer (score 3):

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

> The join method allows one thread to
>   wait for the completion of another. If
>   t is a Thread object whose thread is
>   currently executing,
>
> ```
> t.join();
> ```
>
> causes the current thread to pause
>   execution until t's thread terminates.
>   Overloads of join allow the programmer
>   to specify a waiting period. However,
>   as with sleep, join is dependent on
>   the OS for timing, so you should not
>   assume that join will wait exactly as
>   long as you specify.

I can strongly recommend the Java Tutorial as a learning resource.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the join method on a thread causes the *calling thread* to wait for the thread join() was called on to finish.  It does not affect any other threads that are not the caller or callee.

In your example, A would only wait for B to complete if you are calling B.join() from A.  If C is calling B.join(), A's execution is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if `A` is the current thread running. A call to `B.join()` will suspend it until B's `run()` method completes. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever thread you call B.join() from will block and wait for B to finish.